# Is Microsoft Graph only for Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The reading I'm doing [here](https://blogs.office.com/2015/11/18/today-at-connect-introducing-the-microsoft-graph/) seems to indicate that Microsoft Graph is for exposing Office 365 as an API.
The same link indicates its Office 365 **and** Azure AD. But you have to have an O365 account to interact with the graph.
That eliminates the use case of people who use *only* Azure AD, say for authentication and authorization in SaaS apps.
So, I've been asking about using Micrsoft Graph vs using Azure AD. Is it that as long as I'm not interested in the 0365 side of things that I should stick to the AD graph?

**Update**: Here's a [blog](http://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph) from Microsoft on the matter. They said, "We strongly recommend that developers start using Microsoft Graph over Azure AD Graph, unless specific gaps prevent you from using Microsoft Graph right now."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if all you want to use are directory features, I would encourage you strongly to use Microsoft Graph.  We are adding new directory features to Microsoft Graph that may not show up in AAD Graph and we are busy working to make sure that Microsoft Graph provides all the directory features that AAD Graph provides (and more).

You don't have to have an O365 subscription to use Microsoft Graph (just an AAD tenant) - it's just that Microsoft Graph exposes a lot of rich data that comes from Office 365, including calculated insights.

Please let me know if you are having any challenges with this.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Dan. I've been having issues signing up and using the graph demos using AAD tenant info. I probably haven't found the right tutorial just yet. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of issues you're having?

Comment: I don't think we have any public Graph samples yet that show how to call directory features.  The current samples probably all assume that you have an O365 subscription, and hence call APIs that access Office functionality.  You could look at this UWP snippets sample (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-snippets-sample) that *might* help, but will require some changes.  Is this the challenge you are facing?

Comment: Dan, I checked out and was able to use an account from my AAD directory with the graph example.  I'm going to need to make this work for PHP, so that's the next challenge for me and my team.